# How to compute Jaccard Similarity using gremlin

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am learning about Gremlin and JanusGraph and want to compute the Jaccard Similarity similar to this [Cypher/Neo4j example](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/similarity-jaccard/).

I have case IDs with properties. I would like to compare a give case with all other cases that have a given property A.

Below is some pseudo code:

```
Case1 = [A, B, C, D]
Case2 = [A, B, D, E]
Case3 = [A, C, D]
Case4 = [A, D, E, F]
Case5 = [B, D]
Case6 = [C, D, E]

CaseNew = [A, D, E]

for all cases with property [A]
   compute Jaccard Similarity between CaseNew and CaseN

#this would give the Jaccard Similarity for
#CaseNew - Case1
#CaseNew - Case2
#CaseNew - Case3
#CaseNew - Case4
```

Comment: I just recently answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284061/gremlin-syntax-to-calculate-jaccard-similarity-metric/55287231#55287231

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gremlin syntax to calculate Jaccard similarity metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284061/gremlin-syntax-to-calculate-jaccard-similarity-metric)